# meaning of "practice test notice"

Tags: meaning

[A tutorial](https://youtu.be/GqBbUzejauY?t=44) uses a phrase "practice
test notice" when talking about this answer sheet.

[image]

Does it refer to the area pointed out by red square, the whole piece or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> And in this old practice test,  notice that it says "...."

The word notice is a verb, in its imperative form.  The speaker is telling you to be aware of the something written on the paper.

The "old practice test" is the whole thing, The part in the red box would be called the "heading and instructions for section 1" or more formally the "rubric for section 1"