# "answer sheet" vs. "test paper"

Tags: vocabulary

In post [meaning of "practice test notice"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/254677/115654), I called this thing "answer sheet", then I realized it might be [test paper](https://youtu.be/GqBbUzejauY?t=86) rather than "answer sheet".

[image]

In contrast, the following one is an "answer sheet", though there are some blanks for completion.

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: _Answer sheet_ can be used for either. https://www.lexico.com/definition/answer_sheet

Comment: Oftentimes, individuals in the US born prior to 2000 will use the brand name of a particular answer sheet manufacturer to apply to any generic fill-in-the-bubble sheet. It is termed a “scantron sheet”. This is similar to the usage of the brand name Kleenex to refer to any facial tissue. I am unsure if this term is still in use amongst younger generations. Primarily due to the use of computer administered testing making it near obsolete.